# How do I update a field in the database before my transaction is committed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a password change method, this view is enforced by one of many conditions. The  first condition is if the LastLoggedin field in the database is null. I have this field set to null in my test database to force the password change events.

I have coded a method to change the password after performing some tests, but I cannot get past the first test because the controller method that the click event calls returns the user back to the log on method, which in turns checks the LastLoggedin field in the database which is still null because I have not yet logged in. I tried to change that value from within my change password method using the following code:

```
        public bool SavePassword(UserModel user, PasswordRecoveryModel password)
    {
        try
        {
            string newPass = password.PasswordNew;
            string newHash = PasswordManager.EncryptPassword(newPass);

            User domainObject = UnitOfWork.UserRepository.GetItem(user.EntityId);
            bool hasUsedPassword = UnitOfWork.UserRepository.HasHadPassword(domainObject, newHash, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6));

            if (hasUsedPassword.Equals(true))
            {
                return true;
            }

            User lastLogged = UnitOfWork.UserRepository.GetItem(user.EntityId);
            lastLogged.LastLoggedIn = DateTime.Now;
            lastLogged.VerifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
            UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Update(lastLogged);

            lastLogged.VerifiedOn.Equals(DateTime.Now);
            lastLogged.LastLoggedIn.Equals(DateTime.Now);
            user.Password = newHash;
            user = SaveModel(UnitOfWork.UserRepository,
                                          user,
                                         Mapper.User.ModelToDomain,
                                         Mapper.User.DomainToUserModel);

            CommitTransaction();
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnServiceException(ex);
            throw;
        }


    }
```

But I am still not getting anything other than the new password saved in the database, I am verifying this by running a query on my username. How do I update this field so I can get by this test on password change, and is it even  acceptable to do this? In our old product it was done in a very complex manner creating a temporary user object ant using that to get past the test and on to the next test. I am trying to simplify the process.

I am new to MVC and programming in general any help would be appreciated.

EDIT found my problem, as usual over thinking the issue, here is the updated code:

```
                if (hasUsedPassword.Equals(true))
            {
                return false;
            }

            user.LastLoggedIn = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            user.Password = newHash;
            user = SaveModel(UnitOfWork.UserRepository,
                                          user,
                                         Mapper.User.ModelToDomain,
                                         Mapper.User.DomainToUserModel);

            CommitTransaction();
            return true;
```

Comment: Is the user logged in by this stage?

Comment: @SlightlyMoist at this point they are validated as an actual user, but not logged in yet, there are 3 validation tests left.

Comment: So is your SavePassword method inside a controller with the [AuthorizeAttribute] set? Only logged-in users will have access if that's the case. Try adding the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the action.

Comment: my SavePassword has the [AllowAnonymous] attribute set, the problem is that when the password is saved and the bool evaluates to true. I get thrown back to the top of the validatelogon method and fall back into the forcepassword change chain of events becuase I have never actually logged on.